# Basis to declare variables in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If we are having:

First way is

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController{   

    IBOutlet UILabel* _label;  
    NSString    *myString; 
}
```

Second way is

```
MyClass.m

@interface MyClass() {

    IBOutlet UILabel* _label;  
    NSString    *myString;
}

@end
```

My question is what are the differences between the first way and the second way.

I do know that the second way is create  private variables for MyClass. How is about the first way. Does it do the same or else.

Please advice me on this issue

Answer (score 1):

The first way is the way you would declare it in the header file, MyClass.h. Whoever will use this class will always have your header file, so they'll see those instance variables.

The second way you would use it on your implementation file, MyClass.m. So if you would give me a framework with your class inside, with only the .h file, I would be able to use your MyClass class but I wouldn't know about your instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@private` keyword to make your variables from the first example private. That is not the main point of adding variables in a *class extension*. Rather, adding ivars in an extension lets you remove unwanted dependencies from the header without using forward declarations.

For example, if `MySpecialClass` is defined in `MySpecialClass.h` and you want to add `MySpecialClass *special` as a private variable, doing it in the header would require either a forward declaration `@class MySpecialClass`, or an inclusion of `MySpecialClass.h` header inside your own header. On the other hand, adding a variable to an extension (your second way) lets you include `MySpecialClass.h` in your *implementation* .m file, avoiding the clutter of forward declarations and unnecessary header dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two, the second way is better.  The first way requires you to put internal implementation details in the public interface of your class i.e. it breaks encapsulation by leaking those details to users of the class.

However, now there is a third even better way.  You can put your instance variables in the implementation:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
@private
    IBOutlet UILabel* _label;  
    NSString    *myString;    
}

// method implementations

@end
```